# why can't I delete all files from an azure blobstorage container in databricks

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to remove all files from a blobstorage container using:

> dbutils.fs.rm

Pointing to one specific file like this works fine:

```
dbutils.fs.rm("/mnt/inbox/InvLog.txt", True)
```

But I want to delete *all* content of the container. I have tried the following without success:

```
dbutils.fs.rm("/mnt/inbox/*.txt", True)
dbutils.fs.rm("/mnt/inbox/", True)
dbutils.fs.rm("/mnt/inbox", True)
dbutils.fs.rm("/mnt/inbox/*.*", True)
```

any suggestions?

update: tried ZF007 suggestion %fs rm -r mnt/inbox but it throws error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Try also the non-elegant update :-)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the example given [here](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/dbfs-databricks-file-system.html) you can use `dbutils.fs.rm("/mnt/inbox/InvLog.txt", True)` in a single file method.

The example on the webpage gives you below for a single file:

```
dbutils.fs.rm("/foobar/baz.txt")
```

Removing files under the folder foobar is done like this:

```
 %fs rm -r foobar
```

In your case use:

```
%fs rm -r mnt/inbox
```

Keep in mind the folder-annotation differences between linux, Windows and OSX systems.

Update:

You can try the following non-elegant short-cut solution to circumvent your stated java exception:

```
import os
import ...snippet... # yours to fill in here what else you need to import.

files_processed = 0
files_path = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir()]

print (files_path) # your filepath might need cleaning for it can be accepted. It prints here all found files.

for item in files_path:
    if os.path.isfile(item) == True:
        dbutils.fs.rm(item, True)
        files_processed +=1
    else:
        print ('skipped folder: %s', item)

print ("job done", ' : ', file_processed)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. It throws error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: ... good the read you tried. I'm not an expert on azure-databricks but recommend you update your question with your finding underneath your current provide question text. Use for example bullet name "Update 1:" and state your error in a the yellow box with using ">" sign.

Comment: Your second suggestions returns "Job done" but unfortunately files are not being deleted.

Comment: You might need to check if your filepath is correct so its accepted. See code/comment in script for check.

Comment: It might be that databricks accept `"/mnt/inbox/InvLog.txt"` but not `F:/mnt/inbox/InvLog.txt`... Then reformatting of the filepath is required due to system specific filepath formatting. (answering your question from a windows mache atm.). So in my case it would be 'f:\\mnt\inbox\InvLog.txt`. To see if that is the issue at hand I added a "files_proccessed" checkmark to see if the issue lies there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190303/discussion-between-zf007-and-dennisz).

Answer (score 0):

I found that the command

```
%fs rm -r /mnt/inbox/test
```

only works on a *folder*. not on files directly in a container so in above code, 
*inbox* is the container and *test* is the folder. then it works. files need to be in a *folder*.

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me. It lists all the files in a dbfs folder and deletes them.

```
for filepath in dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/FOLDERNAME'):
  file = str(filepath).split('\'')[1]
  dbutils.fs.rm(file, True)
```

If you want to limit the deletion to any extension (csv in below example).

```
for filepath in dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/FOLDERNAME'):
  file = str(filepath).split('\'')[1]
      if '.csv' in file:
          dbutils.fs.rm(file, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issues I found.

`%fs rm -r path`
OR
`dbutils.fs.rm('path', True)`

Check the `path` whether it is pointing to a "container" instead of a "folder".
We cannot delete azure blob container from databricks.